# SQL to Pandas? Group by and count

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to find the pandas equivalent for the following SQL:

```
SELECT KnownSince, COUNT(1)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY KnownSince
```

I have already tested:

```
aux.groupby(['KnownSince'])['KnownSince'].agg(['count']),  
aux.groupby(['KnownSince']).agg(['count']),  
aux['KnownSince'].groupby(['KnownSince']).agg(['count']),  
aux['KnownSince'].groupby().agg(['count'])
```

But didn't achieve expexted result.

P.S: `KnownSince` is a number in the format YYYYMM and not a datetime object.

Comment: Can you explain the operation you're trying to perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `size`:

```
df.groupby('KnownSince', as_index=False).size()
```

Or named `agg`:

```
df.groupby('KnownSince').agg(count=('KnownSince','count')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas`, build-in function `value_counts`

```
df['KnownSince'].value_counts()
```